# How to destroy and recreate vagrant/homestead machine?

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead

I'm running Laravel on Vagrant Box (homestead)

When I'm doing `vagrant up`, I'm getting a message:

```
: A newer version of the box 'laravel/homestead' is available and already
: installed, but your Vagrant machine is running against
: version '6.3.0'. To update to version '7.1.0',
: destroy and recreate your machine.
```

What commands should I run and what are potential problems I should be prepared for?

Comment: You don't actually *have* to do this - it's entirely optional. Destroying and recreating your Homestead VM will remove any data on it - database, files, etc. - so if you've got irreplaceable stuff in your development databases or in files on the Homestead VM, you'd want to save that somewhere first.

Comment: Good point, thank you. Database is one thing. Source code - is kept outside. Others: 
Nginx - is there by default,
Supervisor - I don't remember, 
Composer - is there,  
Redis is there, 
cron - don't remember...

Comment: This is weird for me. I've created a new folder and `git cloned` [the latest Laravel Homestead](https://github.com/laravel/homestead/releases). So far so good. However, whenever I run `vagrant up` I get the same message `A newer version of the box 'laravel/homestead' is available and already version '11.3.0'. To update to version '11.4.0'`. Then, when I run `vagrant ssh` the server init message is `Homestead v12.5.0 | Settler v11.4.0`. What's the difference of Homestead and settler versions? What does that mean? Why do I get those messages? What am I missing?

Answer (score 11):

You can create a second installation for Homestead before you destroy the working one.

1) follow [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/homestead) on installing Installing The Homestead Vagrant Box, then, when Installing Homestead instead of  this command

```
git clone https://github.com/laravel/homestead.git ~/Homestead
```

run this one

```
git clone https://github.com/laravel/homestead.git ~/MyHomestead
```

then you'll need to `cd ~/MyHomestead` and `git checkout v8.4.0`

now you need to go to `~\MyHomestead\scripts\homestead.rb` file and replace `homestead-7` to `homestead-7-my` it will give you a different name for virtual machine in your virtualbox.

Now you can follow the official documentation

1.1) and you can always destroy your old vagrant box from your vagrant folder usually `~/homestead` by running

```
vagrant destroy
```

2) create a new vagrant box by running

```
vagrant up --provision
```

3) get in to vagrant

```
vagrant ssh
```

4) go to your project (I assume you have a set of database migrations and seeders )

```
cd ~/code/myproject
```

4.1) you'll find `redis` and `mysql` is working there already.

5) create database

```
php artisan migrate
```

6) make SUPERVISOR works if you need it

7) make cron work if you need it

Done

Answer (score 5):

As ceejayoz mentioned, you do not have to do this, you can just continue running the same version. Homestead is meant to be able to be torn down / built back up quickly, with all configuration living within the `Homestead.yaml` and `Vagrantfile` files. It's supposed to be able to do the heavy lifting for you with those config files.

As you mentioned, you have your database in Homestead. If you have some data there that is not local test data, ensure you get that exported before destroying. Some people manually modify their Homestead VM via SSH which is not recommended (as you should be using the `Homestead.yaml` file for changes), but if you have, keep a list of the changes you made and where you made them.

Here is a rundown of things you *may* want to keep before destroying:

- Your `Homestead.yaml` file, just in case
- Your `Vagrantfile` file(s) (if you've made custom changes)
- Database data
- Files used / generated by your application (logs, for instance.)
- [`aliases`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/homestead#aliases) file, if you've made custom changes to it
- [Elasticsearch](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/homestead#installing-elasticsearch) data (if you use it)
- [Neo4j](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/homestead#installing-neo4j) data (if you use it)

As for commands to run, the documentation says it better than I ever could: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/homestead#updating-homestead

Comment: So, practically I need to run `vagrant destroy` and `vagrant up` on my current stage?

Comment: Correct - but make sure you follow the directions in the documentation before that to actually update it first.

Comment: I love Mac time machine for this...destroy the box, make a new one, then jump in time machine and grab your .env and .yaml files from yesterday :)